# Table partitioning using a timestamp and primary key

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I am importing structured log data into MySQL. I hesitate to use the term “big data”, but the size is non-trivial—about 50 columns in the table with the requirement to continuously import 1,000 records a second. There are also requirements that all of this data gets imported to the same table in the same database. Really, the only option I see for any sense of performance (and sanity) is to partition the table structure. Because it’s log data, there’s a timestamp column that I can safely assume a report will include in its query and is a prime candidate for indexing and for use in the partitions’ definition.

Before [Murphy’s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) struck, I was having pretty good luck with something that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `poorly_designed_log_table` (
  ...
  `timestamp` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ...
  INDEX (`timestamp`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (`timestamp`) (
  PARTITION p0001 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01')),
  PARTITION p0002 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-01')),
  PARTITION p0003 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-01')),
  ...
```

I receive the incoming data in batches about 100-200 rows at a time which I push to the database using a transaction and multi-row INSERT statement. But, because of how the data is fed to me, there can be duplicate records between batches. Just as an example, given one batch from 10:30:00 to 10:35:59 and the next batch from 10:35:00 to 10:40:59, records between 10:35:00 and 10:35:59 appear in both batches. In other words, the timestamp column is indexible but isn’t a primary key.

Luckily, there’s a primary key in the data I can use. My intent is to perform an INSERT IGNORE and let MySQL reject the duplicates on its own. I know I need to alter my definition so the primary key is enforced, and I also know the key needs to be included in the partition definitions. The primary key is VARCHAR(36) and takes the following form: *XXXX-<timestamp>-<sequence>*. So for example, the primary keys for three unique records with the timestamp 1499942130 would be XXXX-1499942130-1, XXXX-1499942130-2, and XXXX-1499942130-3.

My question is **how do I define partitioning using the timestamp and the primary key** so that the data is stored in physical “monthly” tables for fast retrieval?

Comment: Since Bill has already nicely solved the partitioning problem, some other aspect: you might want to try [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import you data. Although it has some perks, and while it seems counterintuitive to write a file instead of using `insert` via the api, it can be faster if the batch is big enough, which sometimes might be as small as some ten rows. So it might be worth a try if your general setup supports it (e.g. central client, access to server's filesystem or `local`-support). `IGNORE` works too (`on duplicate key` doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
CREATE TABLE `poorly_designed_log_table` (
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pk` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`,`pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(`timestamp`, pk)
(PARTITION p0001 VALUES LESS THAN (1483257600, MAXVALUE),
 PARTITION p0002 VALUES LESS THAN (1485936000, MAXVALUE),
 PARTITION p0003 VALUES LESS THAN (1488355200, MAXVALUE)
);
```

I had to add the timestamp to the PRIMARY KEY constraint because otherwise you get this error:

> ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

The MySQL Manual on [Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) says:

> All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have.

So it seems to be redundant to make the PK have both columns, but it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! I think I understand... you're suggesting to keep the timestamp range partitions as they are and then use MAXVALUE for the pk, and combine both as the primary. This should force MySQL to organize the data into monthly tables based on the timestamp and then the pk within that table just happens to be whatever it is. Out of curiosity, what does MAXVALUE even mean in the context of VARCHAR, just the max length of the field?

Comment: MAXVALUE is by definition greater than any value in the column. For example, it might be handled as a special case in the partitioning code, not as a real placeholder value like "zzzzzzzz".

Comment: That's a nice workaround. But you might want to add the condition that this only works if the "real" primary key `pk` (*XXXX-<timestamp>-<sequence>*) already contains the `timestamp`-value, a detail that might be missed if the question isn't read carefully. (On the other hand, this comment might be enough to serve as a warning).